# JOIN query to retrieve multiple column referencing to a single column from another table

Tags: sql-server, join

Below is my database diagram which includes three tables and their relations -  `PersonalInfo`,`Subjects`,`Students`

[image: Database diagram]

Currently, `Students` table have below values.

[image: Current data in Students table]

I'm trying to query data to be displayed as below.

[image: Expected output]

**What I tried**

```
SELECT FullName, SubjectName AS 'Subject1', SubjectName AS 'Subject2',
SubjectName AS 'Subject3', SubjectName AS 'Subject4',SubjectName AS 'Subject5' 
FROM Subjects JOIN Students ON Students.Subject1 =Subjects.Id 
JOIN PersonalInfo ON PersonalInfo.Id=Students.StudId
```

Getting below output which is wrong. It's showing only name of the first subject.

[image: Output]

Could anyone guide me the right way.

Comment: you need 1 join for each subject column, so 5 joins in total. But this data structure is wrong (partly because it limits the number of subjects, and makes it hard to report on all subjects together). Instead you need a "Students" table, a "StudentsSubjects" table and a "Subjects" table. Students would just contain ID and name, StudentSubjects would contain just StudentID and SubjectID. StudentSubjects would have a foreign keys on each ID back to the parent table. This is called a many-to-many relationship, something valuable you should learn about for the future.

Comment: @ADyson Thanks for suggestion. I will try that. Appreciate your time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to **join multiple time for each subjects**. There is a confusion in 'Sudent' and 'PersonalInfo' table ids and Foreign keys. So please join it according to the design. Below query will give you all the subject names as you required. Please consider the query as a logic. IT may contain syntax error as I typed it here

```
Select SUB1.SubejctName as Subject1,SUB2.SubejctName as Subject2,SUB3.SubejctName as Subject3,SUB4.SubejctName as Subject4,SUB5.SubejctName as Subject5, from Students S 
    inner join Subjects SUB1 on SUB1.id=S.Subject1
    inner join Subjects SUB2 on SUB2.id=S.Subject2
    inner join Subjects SUB3 on SUB3.Id=S.Subject3
    inner join Subjects SUB4 on SUB4.id=S.Subject4
    inner join Subjects SUB5 on SUB5.Id=S.Subject5
```

Todo - Join with PersonalInfo table to show student name.

Comment: Thanks Vishal. Your query helped. Posting it as answer for someone in trouble like I was.

Answer (score 1):

**Working query**

```
SELECT FullName, 
sb.SubjectName AS 'Subject1', 
sb2.SubjectName AS 'Subject2',
sb3.SubjectName AS 'Subject3', 
sb4.SubjectName AS 'Subject4',
sb5.SubjectName AS 'Subject5' 
FROM Students s 
JOIN PersonalInfo ON PersonalInfo.Id=s.StudId
JOIN Subjects sb ON s.Subject1 =sb.Id 
JOIN Subjects sb2 ON s.Subject2 =sb2.Id 
JOIN Subjects sb3 ON s.Subject3 =sb3.Id 
JOIN Subjects sb4 ON s.Subject4 =sb4.Id
JOIN Subjects sb5 ON s.Subject5 =sb5.Id
```

**Result**

[image: Output]